# Save tuple of arrays (?) as dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, function, dataframe

I have a function in python that returns five arrays. I'd like to turn those arrays into a dataframe `result`. I'll omit the function body for brevity, but this is what my code looks like:

```
def runmodel():
   ## omitting code for brevity
return a, b, c, d, e
```

And then when I run `run model`, I get all this code returned for variables `a,b,c,d,e`.

```
> run()
(array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  7.61377153,  0.        ,  0.        ,
      0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
      2.20431486,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
      0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , 13.94209173,  0.        ,
      0.50471147, 18.42825281,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
      0.        ,  0.        ,  2.03488863,  0.        ,  0.        ,
      0.        ,  0.        ,  1.44420213,  0.        ,  0.        ,
      0.        , 24.76959413,  0.        ,  1.83168143,  0.        ,
      0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.0522511 ,  0.        ,
      0.        ,  1.87509854,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     11.36184872,  0.        , 16.59942782,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     17.33892885,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
      0.        ,  0.        ,  1.28199479, 31.76130032,  0.        ,
      0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     10.29176791, 12.05028586,  5.95222179,  0.        ,  0.        ,
      0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
      2.82531264,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.62874439,  0.        ,
      4.63870345,  0.        ,  0.        ,  6.47953447,  0.        ,
      0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , 17.67837878, 11.08462275,
      0.        , 26.08591628,  4.91841726,  0.        , 12.21861283,
      0.        ,  0.        ,  1.46213229,  0.        ,  0.        ,
      0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.36157407,
     11.74428328,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     10.21569859,  4.02472319,  8.60214736,  6.64881891, 28.73018726]]),
 array([25.]),
 array([1.]),
 array([0.]),
 array([0.]))
```

So, my question is two-fold:

1. What is the technical term for the specific output of `runmodel`? Is it a list of arrays or tuple of arrays.. or something else?
2. How can I turn these arrays into one dataframe? Is that even possible or are they different lengths?

For the second part, I've tried adding the line `result = pd.dataframe({'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c, 'd':d})` in `runmodel`, but then I get the error; `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment`.

Help greatly appreciated. I'm sorry if this is a horrendous question: I don't really even know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific output of runmodel is a tuple of arrays. In order to return them as a dataframe you can do the following:

```
def runmodel():
   ## omitting code for brevity
   result =  pd.DataFrame({
    'Title for a': a,
    'Title for b': b,
    'Title for c': c,
    'Title for d': d,
    'Title for e': e,
    })
   return result
```

In order to avoid the "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment" error, make sure not to use your result variable before you actually assign it to the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I get the error: `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional`. Is it a problem that variable `a` is a different dimension that all the others?

Comment: Actually yeah, if I omit `a` from the DataFrame then it works: so I guess `a` just has to be in its own dataframe..